# Как изменить привязанный файл стилей HTML через JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

В HTML-файле указано:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" id="main_theme">
```

Как на JS при определённом событии изменить `href` на другой файл?

Comment: На всякий случай скажу, Возможно вам не нужен тут js. В некоторых случаях можно обойтись атрибутом media.

Answer (score 0):

Для смены файла стилей, допустим по нажатию кнопки, необходимо:

- Выбрать селектором нужных HTML тег(в данном случае тег style с id='main_theme')
- Заменить значение атрибута href в выбранном теге

> Пример

Есть кнопка

```
<button id="btn">Сменить</button>
```

Cоздаем событие на нажатие кнопки:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
   document.getElementById('main_theme').href = 'css/style2.css';
})
```

Comment: стоит уточнить, что смена href - НЕ очищает уже загруженные стили

Comment: @Grundy Потестил локально. Добавил в первый файл стиль для кнопки, во второй не добавлял. При смене файла стилей, стиль с кнопки слетел. Тестил в edge и хроме

Comment: интересно, почему-то казалось, что после загрузки стили остаются независимо от файла. Возможно с чем-то другим перепутал